# Excel unable to read date&time data

Tags: excel

i have an excel file and facing an issue i.e in column C i haves some value (day:houre:minute:second:000) and i want to minus this value from column D having a different value but with same formatting  but i am unable to get the results in column E. it seems that excel is not properly reading the column C values as i have exported this file from a software.
please help me to solve this issue

[image]

formula used is simply D-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to parse the string to create a true Date/Time then subtract and use TEXT to return the correct string:

```
=TEXT((LEFT(B1,FIND(":",B1)-1) + MID(SUBSTITUTE(B1,":",".",4),FIND(":",B1)+1,999))-(LEFT(A1,FIND(":",A1)-1) + MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,":",".",4),FIND(":",A1)+1,999)),"dd\:hh:mm:ss.000")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply..It works perfectly once again thank you very much

Comment: @AMSINNOVATIONS Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.